# next js type error : s is not a function. This happened when trying to upload an image

Tags: next.js, server, runtime-error

**This is the actual error :**
⨯ TypeError: s is not a function
at F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:6390
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async t0 (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:5773)
at async rh (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:23636)
at async doRender (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1391:30)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1552:28)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1460:28)    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:2101:24)
at async pipe.req.req (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1975:30)
at async DevServer.pipeImpl (F:\Alex stuff\food-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:909:25)
○ Compiling /_error ...
✓ Compiled /_error in 1229ms (1090 modules)

I tried to upload an image using some endpoints but still experience the above error. Tried uninstalling and installing node_module but still did not change, checked the next js version which is up to date.